# Как сохранять файлы[Java]

Tags: java, android

Начал писать блокнот под андроид на Java, и меня заинтересовало, как же сохранять и открывать записи в блокноте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Чтение из файла:**

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

`FileReader` - чтение символов из файла.

`BufferedReader` - используется для буферезации потока.

**Запись в файл:**

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
```

В `fileWriter` можно передавать строку целиком (она автоматически разобьется на символы).

[Вот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MwbLywpV9U) хорошая лекция по данной тематике.